# How to specify order for Javax Validtors in JAX-RS endpoints?

Tags: java, jax-rs, javax.validation

In the following JAX-RS endpoint:

```
public Response myEndpoint(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                                         @Valid
                                         @NotNull
                                         @MyBodyPojoIsValid
                                         MyBodyPojo body) {
}
```

Is it possible to specify that @NotNull will run before my custom validator?

Answer (score 1):

The order of validations can be controlled by [Validation Groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#section-defining-group-sequences) and [`@GroupSequence`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/GroupSequence.html).
Here's an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-groups) on the subject to get you started.